# SWT-Documentation for Swing-experienced developers

Tags: java, swt

Are there good SWT-tutorials for developers experienced with Swing? Which, especially, explain how to do different Swing-features with SWT?

Answer (score 3):

This file might help you: [SWT Eye for the Swing Guy](http://www.slideshare.net/ibogdank/swt-eye-for-the-swing-guy)

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial will help you somehow: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-swing2swt/

For more information, you will have to dig deeper depends on what your problems are. Here are some resources:

- The list of widgets in SWT: http://www.eclipse.org/swt/widgets/
- The best resource to get short SWT
  code is from here:
  http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/
- A larger example can be seen here:
  http://www.eclipse.org/swt/examples.php